# Difference between raising named and unnamed exception

Tags: python, exception

Is there a difference between the following?

```
try:
    <some code>
except SomeException as err:
    raise err
```

---

```
try:
    <some code>
except SomeException:
    raise
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one re-writes the exception's stacktrace from the point it is raised again, so it shows as having been raised at the line `raise err`. The second one leaves the stacktrace alone, so it shows as having been raised somewhere in `<some code>`.

Comment: Note that the difference is in the `raise` statement, not the `except` statement. You can still use the "anonymous" `raise` to pass on the exception even if you've done `except SomeException as err:`.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-raise_stmt), using the `raise` statement on its own just re-raises the last exception that was active in the current scope. `raise err` parses `err[, None, None]` and determines that `err` needs to be raised.

What this means is that the first version (`raise err`) will give the `raise err` line as the base of the stacktrace. The bare `raise` statement goes out and re-raises the last error without touching it, which preserves the original stacktrace.

```
# raise err
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise err
Exception: bar

# raise
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    raise Exception('bar')
Exception: bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `except SomeException as err` will let you then call upon functions of that exception object, as this tutorial snippet shows:

> ```
> except IOError as e:
>   print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)
> ```

You can then reraise it in either snippet.